# Best practise for setting user access?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a user from a form, and a part of the form specifies the user's access rights by selecting checkboxes, and on the validation, i would group those values into a string like : 111 , 011, 101, similar to the chmod codes.

I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it, as the way I am doing seems quite repetitive, or if this is the correct way of doing it at all.

HTML Checkboxes as such

```
<input type="checkbox" name="access[1]" id="ac1"/> <label for="ac1">Consumer</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="access[2]" id="ac2"/> <label for="ac2">Retailer</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="access[3]" id="ac3"/> <label for="ac3">Admin</label>
```

Controller

```
$access = $this->input->post('access');
$user_access = '';  
if(!empty($access[1])) {
    $user_access .= '1';
} else {
    $user_access .= '0';
}
if(!empty($access[2])) {
    $user_access .= '1';
} else {
    $user_access .= '0';
}
if(!empty($access[3])) {
    $user_access .= '1';
} else {
    $user_access .= '0';
}
```

Comment: Having an access system like this based on a fixed amount of integers put next to each other in a string is going to restrict you severely. Do you not have a database wherein you could procure an *actual* role system?

Comment: `if ($access = X) ($chmod = Y)` ? Why to append and dynamicly creat something?

Comment: Working bitwise is kinda heavy for you database, what happens when you have 100 options? you will get 11111111111111.... In my projects, I have included [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)

Comment: The reason for thinking this way was because I wanted to be able to differentiate between users, who might be an Admin but not a consumer, or who might be a consumer and a retailer, or 1 not the other, etc. As far as the number of roles go, they will be a fixed list. But I suppose I should create a table of various roles and their access rights... and build based off that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the access level types in a table in your database.

That way in the future you could check that information like this, once they login.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT access_level FROM user WHERE ID = :userId");
$stmt->execute(array(":userId", $userId));

$userAccessLevel = $stmt->fetch();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT access_level FROM access");
$stmt->execute();

foreach($stmt->fetch() as $key => $value)
{
    $retailAccessLevel = array($key => $value);
}

if($userAccessLevel == $retailAccessLevel[0])
{
    // do stuff
}
else if($userAccessLevel == $retailAccessLevel[1]
{
    // do stuff
}
else
{
    // Tough luck user.
}
```

Then you would have easily accessible variables, one with the users rights, the other with an array of rights. This allows for you to easily change the types or add more access levels in the future, than having to go through all of your code constantly and changing extra information. Please keep in mind, I used PDO and there are betters ways to use PDO than I did, this was just for example purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create constants with the access levels and compare them afterwards. Eg
      `CONSUMER => 1` (lowest access level eg 0 for non-logged in)
     `RETAILER => 5`
      `ADMIN => 9` (highest access)

And then, when evaluating the access, you need to know the level of access required for the current functionality and to compare it.

Eg, if you need access `requiredAccess = 4` for that page/function,
then you can compare like:

`if( requiredAccess <= userAccess ){`
//the user has access
`}else{`
//the user does not have access
`}`

Comment: This will not work if I have a consumer section that is only made available to consumers, retailer section only for retailer, etc. which is what I'm working with..

Comment: @Winterain according to Manos advice, for consumer only access you need to: if( requiredAccess == userAccess ){ /*the user has access*/
}else{ /*the user does not have access*/}

Comment: the point is that if you have only 3 fixed access levels, it's a bit of an overkill to store them in the database. In your case though, you can do it as andrew suggests